# How to understand the proverb:

Tags: proverbs

```
Who stands bail for someone is being teased by the devil.
```

Who stands bail for someone is being teased by the devil.

Comment: Seems to be a German proverb: http://www.special-dictionary.com/proverbs/source/g/german_proverb/86194.htm

Comment: It doesn't really "mean" anything, since this is not a recognised "saying" for Anglophones (is it German, or Spanish?). But certainly ***teased*** is a hopelessly inappropriate translation of whatever the original was.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking the meaning of a poor translation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Teased* is probably *tempted*.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't see how metaphoric "standing bail" would work with that. Perhaps there's a German word that could be variously translated as *vexed / inconvenienced / troubled / teased* or ***prosecuted*** (in the capacity of a prosecuting attorney). But I think it's still an Off Topic translation request, even if OP is unaware of where the text came from.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Try Ger [*reizen*](http://www.dict.cc/german-english/reizen.html). And *bail* probably represents the general sense *surety*: "Don't be tempted into co-signing your friend's mortgage". But I think the real issue for OP is that obsolete *who* at the front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is probably a bad translation from German. I suspect that *bail* means something like *surety*—probably with respect to things like co-signing loan—and *teased* represents *tempted*.

The syntax is another matter. This is a now obsolete usage of *who* where we would now use *whoever*; compare Iago's line in *Othello*, "Who steals my purse steals trash", meaning *Whoever steals my purse will find there's nothing in it*.

You may paraphrase the proverb:

> Whoever co-signs for someone else is being tempted by the devil

Comment: I still don't see how attempting to correct a bad translation when we don't even know for certain what the original meant could be On Topic here. But if it *was*, I think it would be better to "paraphrase" with something that might in principle be said by an Anglophone today in a non-translation context (or at least, without the "mock-medieval proverb" phrasing style). Maybe *You shouldn't tempt fate by standing guarantor for someone else.*